# Is it possible to set a callback on window style change?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

In particular, I'm looking for an approach to get notified when a window becomes always on top window or stops being one. I can easily check if `WS_EX_TOPMOST` flag is set on styles returned by `GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE)`, but I want to be called back on style change instead of polling.

Comment: WM_STYLECHANGING